# Xcode App crashing with no debug information in console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I am using Xcode and for some reason my app is crashing without showing any debug information in the console. It prints code until "distance: (distance)", but after that there is nothing. I am not sure what to fix as there is nothing there to help me in the console. Here is my code:

```
//
//  TableViewController.swift
//  grosseries
//
//  Created by Amish Tyagi on 5/29/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 grosseries. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var ref : DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
    var volunteer : Bool = false
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var destinationCord  = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    @IBOutlet weak var addItemButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        Constants.Storyboard.food = defaults.object(forKey: "foodArray") as? [String] ?? [String]()
        print(Constants.Storyboard.food)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let usersRef = ref.child("Users")
        let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(userID!)
        let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(userID!)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                let userData = document.data()!["userType"]
                if (userData as? String == "Volunteer") {
                    self.volunteer = true
                    self.addItemButton.isEnabled = false
                    self.addItemButton.alpha = 0
                    print("hi!")
                }
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
        // Force the SDK to fetch the document from the cache. Could also specify
        // FirestoreSource.server or FirestoreSource.default.
        docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
            if let document = document {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                print("Cached document data: \(dataDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist in cache")
            }
        }
        thisUserRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = value?["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
            print(value)
            print("username: " + username)
//            let user = User(username: username)
//            if (user == "Volunteer") {
//                self.volunteer = true
//            }
        }
//        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value,  with: { snapshot in
//
//            if !snapshot.exists() { return }
//
//            //print(snapshot)
//            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
//            if let userName = value?["userType"] as? String ?? "" {
//                print(userName)
//            }
//            if let email = snapshot.value["email"] as? String {
//                print(email)
//            }
//
//            // can also use
//            // snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("full_name").value as! String
//        })
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func addItemTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        transitionToNext()
    }
    func transitionToNext() {
        let nextViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "AddFoodViewController") as? AddFoodViewController
        
        view.window?.rootViewController = nextViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    func transitionToInfo() {
        let infoViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "InfoViewController") as? InformationViewController
        
        view.window?.rootViewController = infoViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    func getAddress(address: String) {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
//        var distance = 0.0
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks, let location = placemarks.first?.location
                else{
                    print("No Location Found")
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Location Found, Please enter an valid address or location", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
//                    self.textFieldForAddress.text = ""
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                    return
                }
//            self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: tableView.indexPath(for: "cell"))
            self.destinationCord = location.coordinate
        }
//        if (distance <= 8046) {
//            return true
//        }
//        else {
//            return false
//        }
    }
}

extension TableViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // This part is for later make sure to come back to it
        if (volunteer == true) {
            transitionToInfo()
        }
        else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry, you are not a volunteer", message: "Since you are not a volunteer, you cannot deliver groceries to anybody else. To do this, create another account.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


extension TableViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("insideNumberOfRows")
        return Constants.Storyboard.addressHardCode.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("begin..........")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        var count = 0
        for address in Constants.Storyboard.addressHardCode {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                getAddress(address: address)
            }
//            print(location.coordinate)
            print("destinationCord: \(self.destinationCord)")
            let sourceLocation = (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
            let coord1 = CLLocation(latitude: sourceLocation.latitude, longitude: sourceLocation.longitude)
            let coord2 = CLLocation(latitude: self.destinationCord.latitude, longitude: self.destinationCord.longitude)
            var distance = coord1.distance(from: coord2)
            print("distance \(distance)")
            if (distance<8046) {
                print("count: \(count)")
                cell.textLabel?.text = Constants.Storyboard.namesHardCode[count]
            }
            count+=1
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is a picture of my console:
[image: Image of Console]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.sync` is very bad. Don't do that. It blocks the thread and is most likely the reason of the issue. And it seems that you don't understand how a table view data source works. `cellForRowAt` is called multiple times, once for each row. And it's not the right place to collect location data.